# Is there a better way to query this data?

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Just wanted to run this by some experts and get their thoughts on it. The way I am doing it just feels kinda hacky.

Here is my code:: Basically I find the Groups that the user is a Member of, then search for the group(s).  As you can see I run a for loop that returns the object of each different group. That all works, but the problem is it seems like a lot of querying, and the callback function for some reason runs before the code is done executing.

```
var query = firebaseApp.database().ref().child('members').orderByChild('uid').equalTo(testUID);  
query.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        userObject = childSnapshot.val() 
        userGroups = userObject.groups.groupID

        console.log("User Groups==")
        console.log(userGroups)

        pullGroupInfo(
            function(){
                console.log("###########@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@")
            }
        );
    });  
    // end of get groups quer   
});

function pullGroupInfo(callback) {
    for(var i = 0; i < userGroups.length; i++) {
        /* do some stuff */ 

        var query = firebaseApp.database().ref().child('groups').orderByChild('id').equalTo(userGroups[i]);  
        query.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                console.log("=")
                console.log(childSnapshot.val())
                groups.push(childSnapshot.val())
            });  
        });
    }
    callback();
}
```

Here is my json in case it is needed:

```
{
  "groups" : {
    "-KO0C5FdTWisnc4i9xxM" : {
      "id" : "jkdjsneind",
      "members" : {
        "General" : true,
        "TechChat" : true
      },
      "name" : "joe",
      "type" : "private"
    },
    "-KODDD0C5FdTWisnc4i9xxM" : {
      "id" : "jkdjfbdkbfj",
      "members" : {
        "General" : true,
        "TechChat" : true
      },
      "name" : "jack",
      "type" : "private"
    },
    "-KODDD0C5FdTWisnc4i9xxMxx2" : {
      "id" : "dfdsfds",
      "members" : {
        "General" : true,
        "TechChat" : true
      },
      "name" : "bigcat",
      "type" : "private"
    },
    "dicky" : "d",
    "ggg" : "gg"
  },
  "members" : {
    "-KO0C5FdTWisnc4i9xxM" : {
      "ageRange" : "18-20",
      "college" : "",
      "dob" : "",
      "firstname" : "joe",
      "friends" : {
        "UserID1" : true,
        "UserID2" : true,
        "UserID3" : true
      },
      "groups" : {
        "groupID" : [ "jkdjfbdkbfj", "jkdjsneind" ]
      },
      "lastname" : "caraccio",
      "name" : "joe",
      "pendingFriends" : {
        "UserID4" : true
      },
      "uid" : "6hOnKHBdkMWOaRFKiXyxLkU9lO33"

  }

}
```

Any Help would be great!

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com is a better place to request comments on the style of working code. SO for help fixing problems.

Comment: `query.once()` is asynchronous. You're calling `callback()` without waiting for it to complete.

Comment: ahh, @Barmar . I'll keep that in mind. How would you suggest I get it to wait to complete, is their a synchronous function? How would you suggest solving it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collect all the promises returned by `query.once()` into an array, then use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for all of them to resolve before calling `callback`.

```
function pullGroupInfo(callback) {
    var promises = userGroups.map(function(group) {
        for(var i = 0; i < userGroups.length; i++) {
            /* do some stuff */ 

            var query = firebaseApp.database().ref().child('groups').orderByChild('id').equalTo(group);  
            return query.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
                snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                    console.log("=")
                    console.log(childSnapshot.val())
                    groups.push(childSnapshot.val())
                });  
            });
        }
    });
    Promise.all(promises, callback)
}
```

Comment: this is great, Thank you Barmar!

Comment: that code dosen't run the callback actually.. not sure why

Comment: Promise.all(promises, callback) does not get called. I tried moving it outside of the "var promises = " defintion in guesing it was some sort of mistake, but then it was called prematurely..any ideas? thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake, it should be outside. Try it now.

Comment: "Promises is not defined" .... I am using React Native so I think my issue now is the Promises.all() is not built in.. do you have any other soultions?

Comment: Yeah.. tried importing Promises via NPM and that Didn't seem to work.. just runs the code anyways..

Comment: That was a typo, it should be `Promise.all`. I even linked to the documentation.

Comment: dosen't see to work.. never calls the callback function:/

Comment: However, this does, Thanks so much for your help @Barmar your push in the right direction was crucial

Comment: However what does? If you have your own solution, post it as an answer, don't try to edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of members, you can store the groups like this

```
members: {
    uid: {
        ...
        groups: {
            "-KO0C5FdTWisnc4i9xxM": true,
            "-KODDD0C5FdTWisnc4i9xxM": true
        }
    }
}
```

and then you can do:-

```
firebase.database().ref('members/'+user.uid+'/groups').on('child_added', snapshot => {
    firebase.database().ref('groups/'+snapshot.key).on('value', snap => {
        console.log(snap.val()); //Contains all information about group
    });
});
```